# QMediaPlayer: Sound interrupts when positionChanged() is emitted

Tags: c++, qt, qmediaplayer

i have the same problem like [QMediaPlayer positionChanged(). Sound inteerupts on slider updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969243/qmediaplayer-positionchanged-sound-inteerupts-on-slider-updating)

I use QMediayPlayer and everytime when the signal positionChanged() is emitted to update my slider position and i set a new value to the slider, the sound interrupts for a moment.

This is in the Constructor:

```
soundfile = new QMediaPlayer(this, QMediaPlayer::LowLatency); //soundfile is a pointer of a QMediaPlayer Object

QObject::connect(soundfile, SIGNAL(positionChanged(qint64)), this, SLOT(changedPosition(qint64)));
```

This is the slot function:

```
void Soundfile::changedPosition(qint64 p) {
    QTime time(0,0,0,0);
    time = time.addMSecs(soundfile->position());

    if(p != 0) recordSlider->setValue(p); //THIS IS THE LINE, WHERE IT INTERRUPTS
    changeRecordTime(QString::number(p));
    recordPositionLabel->setText("Aktuelle Zeit: " + time.toString());
}
```

recordSlider is a QSlider.
If i comment out the line with setValue, all works fine.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I think it would help seeing some code, most of all I would like to see the part of code where you create the QMediaPlayer and connect it with messages and slots

Comment: I added the lines of code you wanted to see.

Comment: Do you have no other Qobject::connect involving soundFile ? in particular with soundfile as destination object ?

Comment: Thanks Marco for you help, user2014561 solved the problem.
I had connected the slider and the soundfile with two QObject::connect One is the one you see in the code. The other one is, when the position of the slider was changed, then the setPosition of the QMediayPlayer was called. That ended up in a loop and caused the interrupt.

Comment: You are welcome, please do not forget to give plus 1 if the answer works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the problem is: when the media player emits the `SIGNAL` the `SLOT` is called, and when you use `setValue` inside your function, `setValue` emits the `SIGNAL` again, and the process happens again.

In order to solve that problem I disabled the slider tracking and move the position using `setSliderPosition`.

Example:

```
slider->setTracking(false);
slider->setSliderPosition(pos);
```